# javascript class instance properties to plain object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have an instance of a class, say

```
class MyObject{
    id: number = 0;
    data: string = "";

    constructor(){

    }

    toString(){
        return `${this.id}: ${this.data}`;
    }

    
}

const myObj = new MyObject()
myObj.data = "hello"
```

How to convert it to a plain JS object:

```
const output = {id: 10, data: "hello"}
```

I know this works, but there must be a way without serializing the whole object:

```
const output = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj))
```

What is the best way to do this?

Note that I'm looking for a generic solution, not like this:

```
toObject() {
    return {
      id: this.id,
      data: this.data,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Convert to a what? There's [no such thing as a JSON object](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) and your code example shows you *parsing* the JSON  you create back to a JavaScript object.

Comment: What do you need this plain object for?

Answer (score 0):

To create an object with just the properties and not the methods of an instance, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy all the object's enumerable **own** properties to another object, which can specify as a new, plain, object.

```js
class MyObject{
    id = 0;
    data = "";

    constructor(){
    }

    toString(){
        return `${this.id}: ${this.data}`;
    }

    
}

const instance = new MyObject();
const properties = Object.assign({}, instance);
console.log(properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases you can use the [object literal spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals):

```js
class MyObject{
    constructor(){
        this.id = 0;
        this.data = "";
    }
    toString(){
        return `${this.id}: ${this.data}`;
    }
}

const myObj = new MyObject();
console.log(myObj.constructor.name); // MyObject
myObj.data = "hello";
const result = {...myObj};
console.log(result.constructor.name); // Object
```

If your original object has nested custom objects -- that also need to convert to plain objects or arrays -- then either make a recursive function, or use the `structuredClone` function (added in [ECMAScript 2023](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone), [Node 17](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v17.0.0#other-notable-changes)). Here is a more realistic example with a linked list implementation:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value, next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        yield this.value;
        if (this.next) yield* this.next;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor(...values) {
        this.head = null;
        for (const value of values.toReversed()) {
            this.head = new Node(value, this.head);
        }
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        if (this.head) yield* this.head
    }
    toString() {
        return [...this].join("→");
    }
}

const myObj = new LinkedList(1, 2, 3);
console.log("list: ", myObj.constructor.name, myObj.toString());
const result = structuredClone(myObj);
console.log("list2: ", result.constructor.name, myObj);
```

Note however that this *does* serialise/deserialise the whole object behind the scenes, and where native classes are involved, they are also maintained in the target object (like `Set`, `Map`, `Date`, `RegExp`, `Number`, ...). This may or may not be what you want, but realise that `JSON.stringify` on such instances also has *particular* results: for a `Set`, `Map` or `RegExp` you get an empty object, for a `Date` you get a string, ...etc, so this may need special care -- depending on expectations.